Is there a way to cache JSON data with axios in nuxtjs?
Hello I have simple get request to get data from json. Im using it on several places in my app. Data are not changed often, so is there a simple way how to cache this json only for this request?
this.$axios.get(`${ url }/data.json`)
            .then((response) => {
                    this.dataResponse = response.data.response
                }
            )

I looked for solutions with plugin like 'axios-cache-plugin' but honestly, im not sure its the proper way how to do it.
Site is in Nuxt 2.14.12, and im using Axios module "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5"
thanks

Why not just write your own wrapper function that implements its own cache?

Note that the browser automatically caches the response to GET requests.

@Barmar maybe I just dont know how.

Just create an object or Map that whose keys are the URLs and values are the returned response.

You want your SSR application more fast, with cache it's good.
I think you are looking for axios-extensions: https://github.com/kuitos/axios-extensions
Axios-extensions not only provide cache plugin, also: error retry, and request throttle plugins too.

BTW, Some tips to make your SSR application more stable and faster:

Error retry: Give it a chance to retry when your GET data request errors.
If GET data request errors even after retrying, use the previously successful - - request data to ensure the website doesn't show an error page or crash.
Some request response size is large and not need be real time, to make it fast, we can return cache early and run fetching in the background
Deduplicate requests.

Tips from: https://medium.com/p/8a8f61f30ec5 (Not only for Next.js)
